# Слово "Младенец" с большой буквы, если речь идет об Иисусе?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Например, в названии картины «Богоматерь с Младенцем на троне» верно ли написано слово "Младенец"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) В названиях картин и икон **обычно используется строчная  буква,** например:  Богоматерь с младенцем — икона, созданная в 1884—1885 годах М. А. Врубелем  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BC_(%D0%92%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

2) Однако **авторское название с прописной буквы** тоже сохраняется, в этом случае Младенец или считается **именем собственным**,  или слову придается **высокое значение.**

Answer (score 1):

Прописная буква здесь уместна, ибо речь идёт о Христе.

...С **прописной** буквы пишутся также существительные и прилагательные, употребляющиеся в значении существительных, при именовании Господа и Матери Божией, некоторые прилагательные при именовании Господа и Матери Божией: 
***Богомладенец, Рождшийся, Распятый, Воскресший, Взбранной Воеводе, Заступнице Усердная. "Владычице и Мати Избавителя, приими моление недостойных раб Твоих, да ходатайствуеши к Рождшемуся от Тебе: о, Владычице мира, буди Ходатаица". 
Истинный Бог; Пресвятая Богородица***.[Прописная - строчная. Словарь православной церковной лексики](http://lib.pravmir.ru/library/readbook/125)

Однако в названиях полотен многих живописцев слово "младенец" употреблено со строчной буквы. Так что вариант написания слова выбирает автор картины.